# Symfony's 404 pages return a 200 error code

Tags: symfony, controller, http-status-code-404

I've noticed that when Symfony is displaying a 404 error page (custom or not), it returns a code 200 instead. Is that a default behavior ? I'd like id to return a proper 404 error.

Thanks !

Comment: how have you seen that? a bit of code and explaination would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you have seen that. But that is not correct. If i call a route which doesn't exist. It gives a 404 return.

[image]

[image]

So that is not default behavior. Perhaps you have overwritten something.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, I had overwritten something with Curl !